# mkdir says that file exists when it doesn't

Tags: command-line, mkdir

When I run

```
mkdir ~/.ipython/extensions/
```

I get

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/droudy/.ipython/extensions/’: File exists
```

However when I navigate to `/home/droudy`, there is no .ipython folder or anything resembling that

Comment: Did you use `ls -a`?

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, and it's there, I was only using `dir` and it wasn't coming up, thank you!

Comment: "dot" files, with a dot as the first character, are normally hidden.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, file management tools, such as `ls`, `dir`, or even the graphical file manager, don't show *hidden* files or directories (those where the name begins with a dot, e.g. `.ipython`). This is why `mkdir` is telling you that it already exists, even though you cannot see it by using `ls` or the file manager.

To see hidden files, you can use `ls -a` (From the `ls` manpage : "`-a`, `--all` do not ignore entries starting with `.`"), or, in the graphical file manager (nautilus), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files and directories.